# ServiceStack authentication provider and SOAP conflict

Tags: servicestack

I cannot generate proxy class when authentication provider is enabled.  All DTOs in ServiceStack must be in the same namespace. I get that. Here's where this becomes a problem. Enabling authentication

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider()} ));
```

adds a few ServiceStack resources - Auth, AssignRoles and so on. These DTOs are in the ServiceStack default namespace http://schemas.servicestack.net/types. Now I am stuck - even with the Config.WsdlServiceNamespace and ContractNamespace tricks described in https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support I cannot get svcutil to build a proxy class because my DTOs and ServiceStack provided (which are required for authentication) are in different namespaces.

Can I have authentication provider and SOAP at the same time?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem - did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I could not find a workaround. I believe it is not so much a limitation of Service Stack but rather the fact that REST and RPC (SOAP) are completely different architectural styles. We simply dropped the SOAP.

Comment: Ok - unfortunately I cannot drop SOAP support as it's a business requirement :( I'm going down the road of disabling the Auth plugin and writing a custom request filter to perform the authentication.

Comment: We tried something like that. Be aware of other road blocks along the path of combining RPC/SOAP and REST in one service.  You will be able to get some SOAP out of it, but having a separate WCF service might be an alternative.